# How Can I know date of dropped item in calendar plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a Fullcalendar plugin [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) with dragable it It works Great

now What I already want 
is When I press Save button : TO Loop onto the calendar and track the dragged items and handle it 
when I inspect element I see I can use InnerHtml: but I can't know the DateTime  of the element

[image: as This Picture]
my Inner Html appears as

```
            <div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on">
                    <div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0">
                        <div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end" style="position: absolute; left: 223.6px; width: 106px; top: 136.4px;">
                            <div class="fc-event-inner">
                                <span class="fc-event-title">Villagio door 10</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this is my Draggable Item

```
<div class="fc-event-inner">
                                    <span class="fc-event-title">Villagio door 10</span>
                                </div>
```

I try to loop into div as

```
 $("div.fc-event-inner").each(function () {
                var rr = $(this).fullCalendar("getDate");
                alert("FW: " + rr + ", val: " + $(this).val());
            });
```

Now What I just need it to know the date of this item , something to get its date as "5 April 2016" ???

Comment: please look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:
Use the `EventDrop` eventhandler

> ```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>     events: [
>         // events here
>     ],
>     editable: true,
>     eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
>
>         alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());
>
>         if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
>             revertFunc();
>         }
>
>     }
> });
> ```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Here you can add properties to the event (yes this is possible!)
Add a flag to see if it has been dropped.
see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1hsqo0/)

Then loop over all events and only use the ones that have been dropped